# ConcurrentHashMap.keySet().removeAll() performance issue

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am reading about `ConcurrentHashMap` and checked the removeAll() implementation of its key set. In the current implementation JAVA is iterating the whole key set data structure, even if the given collection contains only one or no elements.

Actual implementation

```
public final boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) { 
        if (c == null) throw new NullPointerException(); 
        boolean modified = false; 
        for (Iterator<E> it = iterator(); it.hasNext();) { 
            if (c.contains(it.next())) { 
                it.remove(); 
                modified = true; 
            } 
        } 
        return modified; 
    }
```

Could some one tell me if this is intended by JAVA developers or i am just over thinking about it

Comment: Where does your "expected" implementation understanding come from?

Comment: I was reading one of the coding blog and found this implementation there,  i thought StackOverflow is a best place to share and understand this that is why i said , correct me if i am overthinking over it

Comment: @Jon Skeet Removing expected implementation as i am not sure, if that is right or wrong so seeking for the best solution here now.

Comment: Without the _expected implementation_ the remaining part of your question doesn't make much sense anymore .... "Did the Java developers intend to write what they wrote?"

Comment: @ShowStopper Is it okay if I make an edit to make it clearer that you're referring to the removeAll method of the key set? It's clear from the question title but less so from the text.

Comment: @G_H where else could the `removeAll()` be? The map itself doesn't have such a method.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I know, but the sentence "I am reading about ConcurrentHashMap and checked its removeAll() implementation." doesn't make that clear. removeAll is also available for the entry set.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou--- Ok you want me to change statement like, "I am reading about entry set of concurrent hash map" that is funny.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `KeySet` in a regular `Map` (like `HashMap`) implements `AbstractSet`. For OpenJDK 8, the source code shows this as the `removeAll` method:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    boolean modified = false;

    if (size() > c.size()) {
        for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            modified |= remove(i.next());
    } else {
        for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

As you can see, there's a check for which collection has the most entries. If the `Set` itself has a larger size, iteration is done over the given collection argument. Otherwise it's done over the entries of the `Set` itself. So if the collection you pass in has no entries, zero actual loop executions are performed. Same if the `Set` itself has no entries.

For `ConcurrentHashMap`, however, the `keySet()` method returns an instance of internal class `KeySetView`, which implements another internal class `CollectionView`. The `removeAll` implementation of that one does conform to the code you posted, which always iterates over the `KeySetView` entries themselves, not the given collection.

The reason for this is likely that the `Iterator`s returned by the views (key set or entry set) allow concurrent access by reflecting the values that are present at the time the iterator is requested. From the Javadoc of `ConcurrentHashMap`:

> Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

So the method forces the use of the key view's `Iterator` itself to take care of consistency across concurrent actions on the view or map.

Note however that the above implementation for `AbstractSet` isn't necessarily optimal either. If the collection `c` you supply as an argument has a larger size than the set, `c.contains(element)` is called for every `element` in the set, but depending on the collection's type that `contains` method might not be nearly as efficient. For an `ArrayList`, for example, `contains` runs in linear time, while presence of the object in a set would be detected in constant time.

Answer (score 2):

### Collection vs. Set

The implementation in question comes from `AbstractCollection` class, while the implementation in solution comes from `AbstractSet` which iherits from `AbstractCollection`.

The performance improvement stems from the fact that in `Collection` you cannot guarantee that the elements are unique, therefore the `size()` call is not enough to optimise the removal. In `Set` however uniqueness is guaranteed, therefore additional assumptions and performance improvements can be made, like iterating through a smaller set when establishing which elements to remove.

### Highly Specialised Map and its sets

The story however is entirely different in both **key** and **value** sets of `ConcurrentHashMap`. This is because `ConcurrentHashMap` is a highly specialised `Map` with many assumptions and improvements for concurrency made. This makes any such generic performance improvements like in `Set.removeAll()` not that valid anymore (in the light of the actual implementation).

`ConcurrentHashMap` iterator is weakly consistent and does a lot of magic behind the scenes. Perhaps `removeAll` on key set is the price one pays for all other performance (from concurrent access point of view) gains.

Just follow `iterator().remove()` on `ConcurrentHashMap` down the rabbit hole of `ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode()`, to see how much logic is hinding in 
[the source code of replaceNode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) to accommodate removal of elements from the iterator.